# In Spring Controller before sending the response to UI, Can we send the response to a class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am tying to remove the httpsession from the cookies in the browser. In that scenario i am trying to point the response from the controller to a class before sending it to the UI. Can anyone please help?

Comment: And why do you need to remove the httpsession from the cookies?

Comment: In my project i have an issue that the sessionid is not getting cleared from the browser cache when the session gets expired. So this is the reason why i am, trying to remove the cookies

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be to implement a custom filter which will invoke request before Controller is invoking the request.
The following tutorial will show how to register a custom filter with spring .

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/